# Somar de valores de coluna em SQL SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, select, tabela-banco-de-dados

Estou fazendo um Select em que preciso que venham alguns dados :

> ```
> Cliente
> Valor Principal Devido
> Valor Multa Devido
> Valor Juros Devido
> Valor Total Devido
> Soma Valor Total Devido
> ```

Porém não sei como fazer que em uma linha seja apresentado a *Soma do Valor Total Devido*. Alguém pode me ajudar? O Script está assim, até então:

```
SELECT C.NomeCliente,
       C.ValorPrincipal,
       C.ValorMulta,
       C.ValorJuros,
       C.ValorPrincipal + C.ValorMulta + C.ValorJuros AS 'Valor Devido Total'
FROM Cadastro.Cleintes AS C
    JOIN Financeiro.Debitos AS D
        ON D.IdPessoa = C.IdPessoa;
```

Comment: já tentou utilizar a função [sum()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_sum)?

Comment: Você quer o total em uma COLUNA (o total de cada linha) ou em uma LINHA (o total de todas as linhas)?

Comment: Queria o total em uma LINHA.. Seria a Soma de todas as linhas da coluna  Valor Total Devido

Answer (score -1):

Altere a linha:

```sql
C.ValorPrincipal + C.ValorMulta + C.ValorJuros) AS 'Valor Devido total'
```

Para:

```sql
(C.ValorPrincipal + C.ValorMulta + C.ValorJuros) AS Valor-Devido-total
```

```sql
SELECT C.NomeCliente,
       C.ValorPrincipal,
       C.ValorMulta,
       C.ValorJuros,
       (C.ValorPrincipal + C.ValorMulta + C.ValorJuros) AS Valor-Devido-total
FROM Cadastro.Cleintes AS C
    JOIN Financeiro.Debitos AS D
        ON D.IdPessoa = C.IdPessoa;
```